# Minimum number queries on matrix

Tags: data-structures, matrices

As part of a solution to an [earlier question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104216/lexicographically-smallest-down-right-path-in-matrix), I am interested in the following problem.

I have a 2-D matrix $M$. I want to preprocess it in linear time so that I can answer queries of the following form in constant time:

> Given $i_1 \leq i_2$ and $j_1 \leq j_2$, what is the minimum of $\{ M_{ij} : i_1 \leq i \leq i_2, j_1 \leq j \leq j_2 \}$?

Such a method is described in [On Space Efficient Two Dimensional Range
Minimum Data Structures](http://tildeweb.au.dk/au121/papers/esa10.pdf), but I am unable to understand it.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Interpreting the whole paper would be too broad to answer.

Comment: imagine there are n queries. In each query, you are given the submatrix(it can be any submatrix) you need to effectively return the position of the minimum number in that submatrix.And all numbers are unique.

Comment: @xskxzr they are doing some preprocessing.

Comment: For your application it suffices to support one-dimensional minimum range queries, for which much simpler data structures exist. See my updated answer to your original question.